# Flink Logging getting job name or job id

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to setup logback.xml so that it will include the JobName or JobId that the logging is associated with.

I have not yet been able to find a way to do this. Is it possible?

Ultimately what I'm wanting to achieve is the ability to have the logs shipped out to ElasticSearch and have the JobName or Id tagged with the message so I'm able to filter by job.

Comment: Did you add this as a seperate JAR or, built it as part of flink codebase.

Comment: The ContextSelector is a separate JAR that you specify when the JVM starts up. See https://logback.qos.ch/manual/contextSelector.html

Answer (score 0):

We ended up doing the following, which felt **super hacky** and we wished we could find a better way.

1. Setup your cluster to use logback
2. Create a custom logback ContextSelector by implementing *ch.qos.logback.classic.selector.ContextSelector*
3. Place your jar in each of your Flink TaskManagers classpath
4. Modify *FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_JM* on each of your flink TaskManagers to specify your context selector. eg:

   > export FLINK_ENV_JAVA_OPTS_JM="-Dlogback.ContextSelector=your.custom.context.Selector"
5. Restart all of your task managers
6. Test it.

Here is a gist of the ContextSelector we created. I'd love pull requests for improvements if you have any!! [Custom Flink Logback ContextSelector](https://gist.github.com/Astn/a02baea87b33f213d0be873879c1a4e2#file-flinklogbackcontextselector-scala)

This creates a LoggerContext for each JobID, and then makes a request to the JobManager using the JobID to get back the JobName. It then splits the JobName by ":" and puts the head component into a LoggerContext Property "flink_job_name" and puts the tail component into a LoggerContext Property "flink_job_version".