# Flink Job ID From within the Streaming Application

Tags: logging, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are running a Flink session cluster and there are a lot of jobs running. I would like to add the jobID as a suffix to any error logs so we can identify which job failed and get notified of the same.

Is there a way to get the jobID of a flink job from within the application? Also, any ideas on how we can write a custom logger to perform the suffix operation?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685485/2000823 will help you.

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg48389.html also relates to this.

Comment: Yes, saw the first Stackoverflow post. It requires us to change logging settings on the Flink cluster. I would like to avoid that if possible. I'm looking for more of a wrapper type solution where I could write a small custom logger using slf4j.